# How to change media upload /storage files in an outside directory like C:\media in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, octobercms, laravel-storage

I created a direcrory outside my OctoberCMS project for media storage i changed the configuration of my local driver in filesystems.php and also cms.storage in cms.php it uploads the images in the  folder but idon't get the real URL when i click on image URL in the backoffice.

Answer (score 0):

change it in bootstrap/app.php:

$app->useStoragePath($yourPath);

Comment: does not working for laravel 5 ! i'm working on October cms